# Calling UpdatePanel in code behind

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an update panel that contains a textbox and some labels, which is contained within a custom user control, which is part of a step in a wizard control. At the moment when the user enters the textbox on the step the update panel fires when the user clicks on the textbox. However, what I want to do is to execute the update panel when the step loads as the textbox value is populated when from the previous step.

Is there away of automatically executing the update panel on the page load method?

Comment: What do you mean with "executing the update panel"? You can call `UpdatePanel.Update()` if that is what you want (you need to make it's `UpdateMode=Conditional`).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Update() method in code behind, but only if you set the UpdateMode to Conditional. Also check that ChildrenAsTriggers is set to false.